# How to use variable length array in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc

So, I've read on this site that c++ doesn't allow variable length array but gcc allows it. So, I wanted to test a small code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

void main()
{
    int8_t n;
    int8_t var_array[n];
    int8_t i;
    printf("Enter array size: \r\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        var_array[i] = i;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("var_array[%d] = %d\r\n", i, var_array[i]);
}
```

The code compiles with "gcc var_array.c -o var_array" command in linux OS but when I run it, I get segmentation fault error

```
Enter array size:
5
Segmentation fault
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *I've read on this site that c++ doesn't allow variable length array* -- No it isn't this "site".  Those are the rules of C++ set by the standard's committee.  A C++ array must use a constant expression to denote the number of entries, not a variable.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie why do you have to come across a mean man. From my reputation, you can tell I am a rookie. You know what I meant by "read on this site"

Comment: You are setting the array size to `n` **before** you give `n` a value. It is probably **zero** at that point (but it could be anything).

Comment: @KharoBangdo *You know what I meant by "read on this site"* -- It gives the impression to other rookies that only StackOverflow members stated this to be true.  You could have simply stated that "C++ does not allow variable length arrays".  My comment is to correct the record.

Comment: Just use a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Besides, just because it compiles does not mean it is correct. GCC by default allows VLAs as a language extension. If you add `-std=c++14` (rather than the default `-std=gnu++14`) and/or add `-Wvla` you should see that VLAs are not allowed by standard C++.

Comment: @JesperJuhl -- For the life of me, I don't understand why gcc allows by default VLA's when compiling C++.  It is leading beginners down the wrong path when they compile code using this syntax.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Choose one (you probably want C, not C++). Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Improve the code to get no warning. Use the debugger. Avoid stack overflows by preferring `calloc` or `malloc` to VLA (at least for large values of `n`). Typical stack frames should be smaller than a few kilobytes

Comment: gcc is the C compiler. g++ is the C++ compiler. If you compile with gcc you should tag this C only. There's nothing C++-specific to the question. Re-tagging this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also make it `int`, as you are using `%d` specifier. (because earlier will only be of 8 bits which might overflow in case of large values)

```
    int n;
    int i;
    printf("Enter array size: \r\n");
    if( scanf("%d", &n) != 1 ){
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Error in input");
        exit(1);
    }
    int var_array[n];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        var_array[i] = i;
      ...
```

You were using an unintialized variable. And then based on new valu eof `n` accessing the array. The indices most probably indexed out of the bound of the array giving you seg fault.

For inputting `int8_t` use `scanf("%" SCNd8, &n);`. You can also input the `int8_t` type.

Yes `scanf`'s return value must be checked.

So the ideal call would be

```
if( scanf("%d",&n) == 1 ){
   //...success..do work
}
```

Comment: But `scanf` could fail, and then the code above has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Answer (score 1):

The Mistake in the program is

```
int8_t n;                  //Here n is declared where n has random value
int8_t var_array[n];       /*Now in this statement you have declared array
                             with the size of that random value*/
```

So You get that error,In order to rectify that you have to get the input value of `n` and then you declare the `var_array[n]`